# Magento Pre Order Product with Date attribute

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento and maybe its a very basic question, but I want to display Pre-Order products on my home page. I have created an attribute `Product_Release_Date` and set it to a future date. When I try to get `Product_Release_Date` its returning blank. What I am doing wrong?

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection(); to get all products
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
<?php  $currentDate = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); to get current date for compare

echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('Product_Release_Date');
```

When I try to display its showing blank, but it returns `productName` and other things. Only this date is not showing. Please help or provide some tutorial where it shows how to enable pre-order.

Answer (score 0):

The `$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('Product_Release_Date');` line is only loading the attribute collection.  You can do this after to see what it contains: `var_dump($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('Product_Release_Date'));`.  If it's `NULL` then make sure your new attribute is really set to `Product_Release_Date` and not `product_release_date` (lower-case).

You can use a "magic get" to retrieve the value, like this:

```
echo $_product->getProductReleaseDate();
```

Here is a fairly recent tutorial on how to enable display of out-of-stock items:

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/103-magento-products-and-inventory-settings/how-to-display-products-that-are-out-of-stock-in-magento

Comment: Thanks for reply, I did var_dump on $_product->getProductReleaseDate(); but it return NULL, but there is value in it, what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: If $_product->getProductReleaseDate() returns null then likely the attribute "Product_Release_Date" is not in the loaded product collection data. Find my answer.

Comment: Yes try @Haijerome's answer.  Be sure to double-check the case of your variable too.  Did you enter it as "Product_Release_Date" or "product_release_date"?  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Its very likely the product attribute "Product_Release_Date" is not in the loaded product collection.

If you need to get it then load the products from Magento Product Resource Model

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach($productCollection as $product):
    echo '<br/>' . $product->getProductReleaseDate();
endforeach;
```

Comment: This will show all of the products.  In his case, he could try:  `$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');`

Comment: @seanbreeden yes he wants to load all products it seems , as we can find from his code comment

Comment: I was demonstrating that he could add the `addAttributeToSelect` to the existing loaded collection.

Comment: @seanbreeden you are right , loading all the product attributes are quite unnecessary load to the database  and doing it in the home page is so pathetic. He must know these two Methods addAttributeToSelect and addAttributeToFilter. If we wants to load only the products with Pre Order Date then you and i know what he needs to do then. cheers !